# How to submit value and show add/remove button?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an array:

```
$userPosts
```

Then I have a form and I check if current page id is there, if so show remove button otherwise display an add button

```
<form id="savedPosts" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="save_post" value="<?php echo $postId; ?>"> 
    if (in_array($postId, $userPosts)) {?>
            <button id="remove_post" name="remove_post" type="submit" class="save_post" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="aggiungilo alla tua box">Remove</button>
        <?php } else {   
        ?>
            <button id="save_post" name="save_post" type="submit" class="save_post" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="aggiungilo alla tua box">Add</button>
    <?php  }
</form>
```

Then I created the send bit:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['save_post'])) {
        $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
        $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
        $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");    
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
    }
    if (isset($_POST['remove_post'])) {
        $userPosts = explode(',', $userPosts);
        if (($key = array_search($postId, $userPosts)) !== false) {
            unset($userPosts[$key]);
        }
        $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
        $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
        $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
    }
}
```

That works, however when I click `add` or `remove` if the `id` is in the `array`, the page sends the correct value but it shows me the old button. I need to manually refresh to display the correct button.

Looks like some sort of caching. I tried to use

```
ob_start();
$myurl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
header('Location: '.$myurl);
ob_end_flush();
```

But I still see the old buttons, not sure if I placed that bit in the wrong position as per the following or it is simply wrong how I used it

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['save_post'])) {
        $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
        $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
        $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");    
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
        ob_start();
        $myurl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        header('Location: '.$myurl);
        ob_end_flush();
    }
    if (isset($_POST['remove_post'])) {
        $userPosts = explode(',', $userPosts);
        if (($key = array_search($postId, $userPosts)) !== false) {
            unset($userPosts[$key]);
        }
        $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
        $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
        $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
        ob_start();
        $myurl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        header('Location: '.$myurl);
        ob_end_flush();
    }
}
```

**WHOLE CODE**

```
<?php 
    global $bodyClass;
    $bodyClass = "single";

/*
    Template Name: External
*/

    include ('header_single_b.php'); 
?>

<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">

    <?php
        $postId = $_GET['postId'];
        $allposts = '';
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $userPosts= get_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', TRUE );
        $userPosts = explode(',', $userPosts);
        $userPosts = array_values(array_unique($userPosts));
        $response = wp_remote_get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include='.$postId);
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
            return;
        }
        $posts = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
        if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
            return;
        }
        // If there are posts.
        if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
            // For each post.
            foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                $allposts .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $post->link ) . '" target=\"_blank\">' . esc_html( $post->title->rendered ) . '</a>  ' . esc_html( $fordate ) . '<br />'.$post->content->rendered;
            ?>
            <div class="container margin-top-80 margin-bottom-80">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <form id="savedPosts" action="" method="POST" class="" autocomplete="off">
                            <input type="hidden" name="save_post" value="<?php echo $postId; ?>"> 
                            <?php
                                if (in_array($postId, $userPosts)) {?>
                                        <button disabled="disabled" type="submit" class="save_post disabled btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="già nei tuoi favoriti">Già nella box</button>
                                        <button id="remove_post" name="remove_post" type="submit" class="save_post" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="aggiungilo alla tua box">Rimuovi dalla box</button>
                                    <?php } else {   
                                    ?>
                                        <button id="save_post" name="save_post" type="submit" class="save_post" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="aggiungilo alla tua box">Salva nella box</button>
                                <?php  }
                            ?>
                        </form>
                        <hr>
                        <h2><?php echo esc_html( $post->title->rendered ); ?></h2>
                        <p><?php echo $post->content->rendered; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }
        }
        if (!in_array($postId, $userPosts)){
            array_push($userPosts,$postId);
        }   
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
            if (isset($_POST['save_post'])) {
                $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
                $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
                $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");    
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
            }
            if (isset($_POST['remove_post'])) {
                $userPosts = explode(',', $userPosts);
                if (($key = array_search($postId, $userPosts)) !== false) {
                    unset($userPosts[$key]);
                }
                $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
                $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
                $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
            }
        }
    ?>
</main>
<?php include ('footer_single_compare.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Can i see the whole code? Where have you put HTML form and that PHP processing code? To plugin's file or theme's functions.php?  Inside HOOK or directly to some file? These are very important moments.

Comment: @ElvinHaci updated the question with the whole code. It is not a plugin, it is a custom template page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using WordPress HOOKS and write your code directly, your PHP code would run form top to bottom.

And in your case your PHP processing block comes after your HTML form.
That's why it has to show old data.

To solve this just move that block to the top part, and it will work ok.

For example, you can put it just before the line

```
if ( ! empty( $posts ) )
```

It should look like this

```
        if (!in_array($postId, $userPosts)){
            array_push($userPosts,$postId);
        }   
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
            if (isset($_POST['save_post'])) {
                $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
                $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
                $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");    
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
            }
            if (isset($_POST['remove_post'])) {
                $userPosts = explode(',', $userPosts);
                if (($key = array_search($postId, $userPosts)) !== false) {
                    unset($userPosts[$key]);
                }
                $userPosts = implode(',', $userPosts);
                $userPosts = trim($userPosts);
                $userPosts = ltrim($userPosts, ",");
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post', $userPosts );
            }
        }

if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
```

Comment: gives me `Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in.. line 68` which is  `if (in_array($postId, $userPosts)) {`

Comment: it is because you are using $userPosts as array and as string as well. Which is not good practise. Try to add $userPosts = explode(',', $userPosts);  before if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) then

Comment: ok thanks works. I use implode for that array as I am sending it to a custom user meta, I cannot send the array as a value or can I? Anyhow you could show me the best pratice? I'd like to learn thanks

Comment: You don't need to stringify or trim values for update_user_meta.  Just use update_user_meta($user_id,'name',$array_variable);  and it will work without any problems. Later, get_user_meta for that key will directly return array variable. Without needing explode()

Comment: mm that makes the remove button available as it is checking if the postId is in the array and adding it and if it's there, then the remove button it shown, even tho we don't have it in the user meta. We should do `if (isset($_POST['save_post'])) {
        array_push($userPosts,$postId);`

Comment: actually on submit now it is a string while it expects an array, as if the session is in cache

Comment: if your problem isn't solved yet, you can update your question with the last state of your code and describe the last problem you have